# lambda create-event-source-mapping Member must not be null Exception

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cli, amazon-kinesis

I am trying to attach a kinesis stream event to lambda function usi cli command but getting exception as :

An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateEventSourceMapping operation: 1 validation error detected: Value null at 'startingPosition' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null.

My command is :

```
aws lambda  create-event-source-mapping --event-source-arn arn:aws:kinesis:us-west-2:xxxxxx:stream/lambda-stream --function-name helloworld-divyanayan_lambda --batch-size 100
```

Comment: document for reference https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/create-event-source-mapping.html

Comment: aws lambda  create-event-source-mapping --event-source-arn arn:aws:kinesis:us-west-2:xxxxxx:stream/lambda-stream --function-name helloworld-divyanayan_lambda --batch-size 100 --starting-position Latest. i think it is required field as by default no starting position is set

Answer (score 2):

If Lambda is your consumer for Kinesis streams where you are continuously processing stream data, you use "LATEST" as the starting position.

TRIM_HORIZON will read the oldest untrimmed record in the shard.

Comment: Thanks for replying ..but my question was not on diffrence between TRIM_HORIZON and LATEST,rather i was trying to map a kinesis event to lambda function  using command line .so after giving --starting-position in command line ,cli command executed successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error for a DynamoDB stream mapping to a Lambda in CloudFormation.  As other answer/comment suggests, the problem is the starting position on the Kinesis stream.

[The CLI docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-ddb.html) do indeed have a flag for `--starting-position`, and the CloudFormation template [does as well](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-eventsourcemapping.html#cfn-lambda-eventsourcemapping-startingposition).

So, in my case, it was fixed by adding this line to my CFN template:

```
Type: AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping
    Properties: 
      ...
      StartingPosition: 'LATEST'
```